# “Sur le côté droit” or “Au côté droit”?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

When giving directions which is better?

> Tu le verras au côté droit.
>   Tu le verras sur le côté droit.

or something else?

> ... à ton côté ...
>   ... sur ton côté ...

Comment: What should he see and on the right side of what ? In the meantime, I suggest *Il sera à droite* or *ça sera à droite*

Comment: _Tu le verras à ta droite_ or _Tu le verras sur ta droite_

Answer (score 3):

> Tu le verras au côté droit.

is tricky to use. This expression only relates when referring to persons, and not objects. ([source)](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article308)

> Tu le verras sur le côté droit.

is correct, and is used in oral French. It lacks precision (on the right side of what?). The suggestions of MrSmithGoesToWashington and jlliagre are better :

> Tu le verras sur ta droite.

Regarding your other suggestions :

> ... à ton côté ...

means "close to you" (could not find a reference for this).

Answer (score 2):

We actually go for a much simpler way to say it :

> Tu le verras sur ta droite.

This also applies on your left.

Comment: what means the 'le' here? You are going 'it?!' on your right....

Comment: « Tu le verras » means "You will see it"

Comment: Now I feel silly... of course, I was thinking 'viendras'